# add number value from radio checked to span, then add/remove number value from separate checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, radio-button

i have a number of quantities that are available to select by radio, and i want the price of that to show up in the TotalPrice span. however i also have another checkbox below the quantities for a shipping option that i would like added onto the TotalPrice span on top of the quantity price.

```
<tr style="text-align: center;">
  <th scope="row">
    <input
      class="form-check-input"
      type="radio"
      name="quantity"
      id="quantity1"
      value="1"
    />1
  </th>
  <td>FREE + $6.97 S&H</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center;">
  <th scope="row">
    <input
      class="form-check-input"
      type="radio"
      name="quantity"
      id="quantity2"
      value="2"
    />2
  </th>
  <td>FREE + $9.97 S&H</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center;">
  <th scope="row">
    <input
      class="form-check-input"
      type="radio"
      name="quantity"
      id="quantity4"
      value="4"
    />4
  </th>
  <td>FREE + $16.97 S&H</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center;">
  <th scope="row">
    <input
      class="form-check-input"
      type="radio"
      name="quantity"
      id="quantity6"
      value="6"
    />6
  </th>
  <td>FREE + $21.97 S&H</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center;">
  <th scope="row">
    <input
      class="form-check-input"
      type="radio"
      name="quantity"
      id="quantity8"
      value="8"
    />8
  </th>
  <td>FREE + $26.97 S&H</td>

  <input
    class="form-check-input"
    type="checkbox"
    name="ship"
    value="Expedited"
    id="exp1"
  />

  <span id="TotalPrice"></span>
</tr>
```

also, is it possible for the values (quantity, expedited & TotalPrice) to be sent thru and picked up via $_POST in php?

Answer (score 0):

To update the quantity in the span , I would suggest using a function that gets the "checked" property of buttons and returns the corresponding value printing it in the span, like

```
function updateValue() {
    var qty=0
    var elems=document.getElementsByClassName("form-check-input");
    for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
        if(elems[i].checked) {
            qty=elems[i].value //put price in value before
            break //got the one we want, stop searching
        }
    }
    var chkbox=document.getElementById("exp1")
    var chkstr=chkbox.checked?chkbox.value:""
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML=qty+chkstr
}
```

to send it to PHP, put it all in a form with `action="/path/to/php"` and `method="post"`; that will send whatever the values are to the $_POST variable in PHP (ex quantity in $_POST["quantity"] with your code).